# Make json from post a string in controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller

Hello everyone I currently have an example of what I need with this table

```
<table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="tableID">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">val1</td>
      <td align="center">val2</td>
      <td align="center">val3</td>
      <td align="center">1500</td>
      <td align="center" class="myID"><input type="number" name="txtID" class="txtID" oninput="setValueAttr(this)" value="" min="0" max="1000"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">val1</td>
      <td align="center">val2</td>
      <td align="center">val3</td>
      <td align="center">1500</td>
      <td align="center" class="myID"><input type="number" name="txtID" class="txtID" oninput="setValueAttr(this)"  value="" min="0" max="1000"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">val1</td>
      <td align="center">val2</td>
      <td align="center">val3</td>
      <td align="center">1500</td>
      <td align="center" class="myID"><input type="number" name="txtID" class="txtID" oninput="setValueAttr(this)"  value="" min="0" max="1000" ></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<form>
<button type="button" onclick="aplicar()">Aplicar</button>
</form>
<script>
function setValueAttr(el){
  el.setAttribute('value', el.value)
}

function aplicar(){
    var myTab = document.querySelectorAll('#tableID tbody tr .txtID:not([value=""])');
    var tableData = [];
    Array.from(myTab).forEach(input => {
      var tds = input.closest('tr').children;
      var obj = {};
      obj.A = tds[0].textContent;
      obj.B = tds[1].textContent;
      obj.C = tds[2].textContent;
      obj.D = tds[3].textContent;
      obj.E = input.value;
      tableData.push(obj);    
    });
        tableData = JSON.stringify({ 'tableData': tableData });
            $.ajax({
            url: '@comercial.Models.Base.DirectorioRaiz()Controller/View',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: tableData,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#divPagosAplicados').html(response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
}
</script>
```

And I saw a way to receive this json in my controller like this

```
public class tableData
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
    public string E { get; set; }
}


public void View(List<tableData> tableDatas)
{
    var t = tableDatas;

}
```

However I need to perform something like I do on this javascript but in my controller.

```
var total = [];
for (i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    total[i] = "&num_operacion" + (i + 1) + "=" + tableData[i].A +
        "&monto" + (i + 1) + "=" + tableData[i].E +
        "&num_documento" + (i + 1) + "=" + tableData[i].B +
        "&tipo_documento" + (i + 1) + "=" + tableData[i].C
}
```

I have accomplished this using that javascript and sending the string with post but if string is large enough ajax will crash

Comment: are you saying List<tableData> tableDatas is not getting populated after post?

Comment: Basically what it does is this, if we type something on the txtbox of the table rows, and it's not over the max value it will be saved in an array and then I will JSON.stringify it to post it as a JSON to my controller, my controller says it's null  :( but in the debugger it hits on the variable, anyway I plan to make this post into a string inside my controller how can I do this? 

edit: okay i noticed that I havent declared the list in the controller and that's why it's null I'm figuring out how-to fix it lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to make a Model instead of doing the class inside the Controller so..

Model.cs

```
    public class tableData
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
        public string C { get; set; }
        public string D { get; set; }
        public string E { get; set; }
    }
```

And changed controller to this

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Index(List<tableData> tableDatas)
        {
            List<string> total = new List<string>();

            for(int i = 0; i < tableDatas.Count(); i++)
            {
                total.Add($"&num_operacion{i+1}={tableDatas[i].A}&monto{i+1}={tableDatas[i].E}&num_documento{i + 1}={tableDatas[i].B}&tipo_documento{i + 1}={tableDatas[i].C}");
            }

            return Json(total);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `[FromBody]ModelName` helper in your action method to bind it to your expected model

```
public IActionResult([FromBody]List<MyModel> model)
{
............
}
```

Comment: Mhmm I'm reading how to use [FromBody] if you have time can you please use data of my example using your code suggestion?